# Reading barcode using vb.net code

Tags: vb.net

I need to add barcode reading feature to my application.  I donot know how to enable my application to read barcodes.

I mean a scanner should read the barcode and having matched the article no. in database, info should be displayed on the screen.

Any code examples please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most barcode scanners act like a keyboard.

There isn't anything special required.

Some scanners can send special key sequences so that you can focus the appropriate text field.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to read from barcode you need to read the serial port

> Blockquote

```
  Private Sub modem_open()
    Dim MyportName As String ="COM1"
    Try
        Me.SerialPort1.PortName = MyportName
        If Not Me.SerialPort1.IsOpen Then
            SerialPort_Init(Me.SerialPort1)
            Me.SerialPort1.Open()
        End If
        SerialPort1Timer.Enabled = True
    Catch ex As Exception
                  modem_close()
    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub modem_close()
    SerialPort1Timer.Enabled = False
    Try
        Me.SerialPort1.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub SerialPort1Timer_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SerialPort1Timer.Tick
    Try
        Dim bufferEnd As Boolean = True
        Dim modem_Answer_Line As String
        modem_Answer_Line = ""
        modem_Answer_Line = SerialPort1.ReadExisting
        If modem_Answer_Line <> "" Then
                       Bnt_Close.PerformClick()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
       
    End Try
End Sub
```